# RVM environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

For my Ruby on Rails project I have to do a lot of stuff in the command line, like running rake tasks or running test specs. In my app I need to supply an environment variable to do this, e.g. `ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=bla rake db:test:prepare`

What is a good way to add environment variables to RVM, so I don't have to use the variable every single time in the command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your applications folder you can place a .rvmrc file with the settings you need for your project. This file is read, when you change to this directory. E.g, I have a .rvmrc with this content:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320
couchdb -b
```

When I enter the applications folder, rvm is firing a hook with parsing the file contents:

```
cd project/
Using /Users/andwen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
Running /Users/andwen/.rvm/hooks/after_use
Apache CouchDB is running as process 39539, time to relax.
Running /Users/andwen/.rvm/hooks/after_cd
```